# Is it possible to get How many people is watching YouTube live video via YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am going to build an application with YouTube API. Where I'm getting video event from API and playing the video on a website when that gets live.

I'm getting all the data I need except how many people watching the video.

Is there any way to get that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get those statistics by requesting `liveStreamingDetails` part when requesting video details. Here is a sample HTTPS request ([ref](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list)):

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2Cstatistics%2CliveStreamingDetails&id=21X5lGlDOfg&key=[YOUR_API_KEY] HTTP/1.1

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json
```

And the result:

```javascript
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/ARYNDpdj0hFzJ8zKV9SLVLV4PWE\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/_SdqmAfikf6n_Jny6hfytlYz1wY\"",
   "id": "21X5lGlDOfg",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-12-28T18:40:15.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCLA_DiR1FfKNvjuUpBHmylQ",
    "title": "NASA Live: Official Stream of NASA TV",
    "description": "Direct from America's space program to YouTube, watch NASA TV live streaming here to get the latest from our..."
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "8512883",
    "likeCount": "130811",
    "dislikeCount": "6836",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "0"
   },
   "liveStreamingDetails": {
    "actualStartTime": "2018-12-28T18:41:30.221Z",
    "scheduledStartTime": "2018-12-28T19:00:00.000Z",
    "concurrentViewers": "108"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Have a look at `concurrentViewers` element.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can request the video object and get the amount of concurrent viewers via `liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers`

Here is the API doc reference: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#liveStreamingDetails.concurrentViewers

It would be a request like this for example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=liveStreamingDetails&id={YT ID}&fields=items%2FliveStreamingDetails%2FconcurrentViewers&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```